# React component doesn't import font awesome less/css file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, font-awesome

I am trying to use react-fontawesome in my application. Below is my react component class:

```js
import React from 'react'
import 'font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less'
import FA from 'react-fontawesome'

export default class SearchField extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (<div className={this.props.className.length===0?'search-field':this.props.className}>
      <p>{this.props.text}</p>
      <FA name='twitter'  />
    </div>)
  }
}
```

I have imported the font-awesome.less but the icon doesn't show on the browser. I can see the classname has been set on the dom but there is no css style associated with the dom. I also tried to import the css file as below but it still doesn't work.

`import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'`

what wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you see if there are any styles from font-awesome injected or loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an `less` loader for webpack:

```
module: {
     loaders: [
        { test: /\.less?$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'less'] }          
     ]
}
```

You might even need to load the icons (fonts) like:

```
{ test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```